# python code doesn't work when I segregate into packages | works fine in same file

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build some restful API's. When I try to segregate code into packages the service doesn't work and I get *URL not found on the server.* For examples:

**Scenario 1** [Works fine as I have everything in main.py]

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def echo():
    message = request.get_json().get('message', '')
    return jsonify({'message': message})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Now when I try to segregate the code into different packages, it just doesn't work. For example:

**Scenario 2** [Doesn't work as the code is in different packages]

I am initializing the app in *api/restful.py*

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Then created a service in *api/endpoints/service.py*

```
from api.restplus import app, jsonify, request

@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def echo():
    message = request.get_json().get('message', '')
    return jsonify({'message': message})
```

Finally in *main.py*

```
from api.restplus import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

It seems like the service is not visible to the app when I put it in a different package. Please advise.

Comment: Can you please describe *how* "it just doens't work"? Do you get errors? Or something else? Please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally, `restplus` or `restful`?

Comment: Oh, and should you not import the *service* anywhere?

Comment: You may not want to complicate the stuff by adding things to different files which has no big usefulness. It would probably complicate things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I am getting *URL not found on the server* exception while sending a request from postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the issue you get is that flask does not see your service it looks like nothing is importing your service code once you split your code.

Simply modify your *main.py* file to look like this to fix it:

```
from api.restplus import app

import api.endpoints.service

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this way Or I would suggest, if there are less routes try to have everthing in one file.

```
from yourfile import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

In yourfile.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def echo():
    message = request.get_json().get('message', '')
    return jsonify({'message': message})
```

Comment: Actually, I have over 20 routes. So I was thinking to have separate files. Thanks a lot for the quick help!

Comment: Still 20 routes is not much I feel. Maintaining many files would be a issue later.

Comment: Two files may help you maintain it.

Comment: I see. I will have all of them in one python file and will import it in main. I just wanted to avoid having a lot of code in main.py.

Comment: Yeah that would be maintainable.